# How to download multiple files as zip in vb.net. Lost my extension while downloading in firefox

Tags: vb.net

I am downloading multiple files as a zip file in vb.net. Some of the browsers doesn't add it as a zip file.

My code is:

```
If Not IsPostBack Then
        If Not Session("x") = Nothing Then
            Dim x As String = Session("x").ToString
            Dim path() As String
            path = x.Split("|"c)
            Using zip As New ZipFile()
                zip.AlternateEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
                zip.AlternateEncodingUsage = ZipOption.AsNecessary
                For i = 0 To UBound(path)
                    If Len(path(i)) > 0 Then
                        Dim filePath As String = Trim(path(i))
                        zip.AddFile(filePath)
                    End If
                Next
                Response.Clear()
                Response.BufferOutput = False
                Dim zipName As String = [String].Format _
                 ("Datas_{0}.zip", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"))
                Response.ContentType = "application /zip"
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + zipName + "")
                zip.Save(Response.OutputStream)

                HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()

                Response.Flush()
                Session.RemoveAll()
                Session.Clear()
                Session.Abandon()

            End Using
        Else
            Response.Redirect("frmUser.aspx")
        End If
    End If
```

My files are downloading as a zip file in Chrome and IE But in Firefox it downloading as a xml files sometimes and sometimes its downloading without any extension. I dono whats the actual problem is?

Comment: `application /zip` should be `application/zip` perhaps?

Comment: Is space also consider to add the extension??

Comment: no idea what you're on about ... the mime type for a zip file is `application/zip` not `application /zip` is all I'm saying

Comment: Okay will correct it now.

Comment: I changed my `content-type` as `application/zip` but now its downloading as an windows application in Firefox only. I want to download it as zip file.

Comment: try `application/x-zip-compressed` - though I've used `application/zip` successfully in chrome and firefox for years! another alternative is `application/octet-stream`

Comment: Yeah it worked now. I used both `application/x-zip-compressed` and `application/octet-stream`.   using `application/octet-stream` also occurs same problem but `application/x-zip-compressed` downloads as what the content-type is. Thank you so much.